# How equals 3 ArrayList<String> and check matches of objects in this lists?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have 3 List of String

```
private @Getter @Setter List<String> allowedServicesId;
private @Getter @Setter List<String> notAllowedServicesId;
private @Getter @Setter List<String> replaceServiceId;
```

And I need check Is there at least one intersection of the object in these lists?

I have created this

```
        for (String s : allowedServicesId) {
            if (notAllowedServicesId.contains(s)){
                throw new Exception("");
            }
            if (replaceServiceId.contains(s)){
                throw new Exception("");
            }
        }
        for (String s : notAllowedServicesId) {
            if (replaceServiceId.contains(s)){
                throw new Exception("");
            }
        }
```

but I think it is bad practice. I think there is another way.

**EDIT**

I figured it out

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(allowedServicesId);
        set.addAll(notAllowedServicesId);
        set.addAll(replaceServiceId);
        int i = allowedServicesId.size() + notAllowedServicesId.size() + replaceServiceId.size();
        if (set.size()!= i){
            throw new Exception("");
        }
```

as you?

**EDIT**

I can change `List` to `Set`

```
private @Getter @Setter Set<String> allowedServicesId;
private @Getter @Setter Set<String> notAllowedServicesId;
private @Getter @Setter Set<String> replaceServiceId;
```

If it's easier

Comment: Yeah... Well, you have a loop within your loop, checking for the same thing twice. That isn't really necessary ô.ô...

Comment: @Ephi it doesn't solve the problem, it just makes the code shorter. The problem is - what if you had - say - 10 arrays? Man I cannot imagine that...

Comment: should your code allow duplicates?

Comment: you set code will fail if one list contains twice same id

Comment: one list can not contain two identical values. it is in my case. but your comment is true

Comment: better maintain a hashset for further lookup instead of creating a hashset for every lookup.

Comment: It seems that you are keeping 3 lists, or sets, to maintain exclusive attributes for your services (as in, a service can be either `allowed` or `replaced` or `notAllowed`). You should place these attributes in the services themselves, by defining a `Service` class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already found an acceptable answer with the idea of adding the three lists into a set. Here's an equivalent and more generic Java 8 code

```
private static void assertForDuplicates(Collection<?>... collections) throws Exception {
    int n = 0;
    for (Collection<?> c : collections) {
        n += c.size();
    }

    if (Stream.of(collections).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() != n) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: However, this is potentially slow. Say that you detect a duplicate among the 1st two elements. Why continue until the end before complaining?

Comment: @tucuxi You're absolutely right. Performance-wise my solution is by far not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the three sets** instead of lists. This has several advantages:

- Since each of the sets should not contain duplicate elements, using `Set` (which does not allow such duplicate elements to coexist) is both clearer and can avoid potential bugs.
- Set operations (add, contains, ...) are much more efficient than list operations. In particular, finding an element in a list is O(|size of list|), and O(1) in a `HashSet`.

Assuming you are using sets, the following code is an efficient way to test for duplicates in sets of `String`:

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Set<String> ... sets) {
    if (sets.size() < 2) return false; // no possible duplicates
    Set<String> all = Hashnew Set<>();
    for (Set<String> set : sets) {
        for (String s : set) {
            // adding to a set returns false if element was already there
            if ( ! all.add(s)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This fails as soon as the first duplicate is found (and could be easily modified to report where the match took place). In the worse case, it is equivalent to your code that adds all elements and then tests to see if the total size is as expected.

---

**Edit - a different take**

You seem to be using multiple hashsets to keep exclusive boolean attributes for your services. Consider creating a `Service` class instead:

```
public class Service {

    public enum Status { ALLOWED, REPLACE, NOT_ALLOWED };

    private String id;
    private Status status;

    // constructors, getters & setters here

    public int hashCode () { return id.hashCode(); }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        return o instanceof Service && id.equals(((Service)o).getId()); 
    }        
}
```

This allows you to keep a single set:

```
Set<Service> services; // guaranteed: each has exactly one status
```

Even better, you would use a map to retrieve services efficiently by their id:

```
Map<String, Service> servicesById; 

Service httpService = servicesById.get("http");
System.out.println("The status of service http is " + httpService.getStatus());
```

Comment: I think (although I'm not the OP) that the second approach goes beyond the OP questions and is exactly what we can expect from a quality answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

A good blend of efficiency and elegancy may be:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
if (Stream.of(allowedServicesId, notAllowedServicesId, replaceServiceId)
        .flatMap(List::stream).anyMatch(s -> !set.add(s)))
    throw new Exception();
```

Or more useful:

```
Optional<String> dupe = Stream.of(allowedServicesId, notAllowedServicesId, replaceServiceId)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(s -> !set.add(s))
        .findFirst();
if (dupe.isPresent())
  throw new Exception(dupe + " was duplicated");
```

which tells you *which* item was duplicated.

Both versions of code will throw an exception as soon as the first duplicate is found.